# dot plot color using geom_dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make just the dot plot points be colored using the data$color vector? There should be one red point on the plot

```
t =c(c(10,4,5,6,7,8,15,2),c(2,5,5,14,16,8,15,17))
g =c(  rep("A",8),rep("B",8))

data = data.frame(group = g ,t = t)
data$label = ""
data$label[10]= "g"
data$color =""
data$color[10]= "red"

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

myfun<- function(x) {
  r <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95))
  names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  r
}


 ggplot(data, aes(x=g, y=t,label = label 
)) + theme_bw()+
  stat_summary(fun.data = myfun, geom="boxplot")  +
   geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=.5, color = color)
```

I get an error saying:  object 'color' not found

Comment: Look at `data` - it does not contain a column called `color`. Try to fix this line `data$color[10]= "red"`. What do you try to achieve with that?

Comment: updated the data frame

Comment: Now use `aes(color = color)`. But the output might not exactly be what you are looking for, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ggplot doesn't seem to be looking in data to find the color variable, so you need to tell it where color is located. This worked for me:

```
t =c(c(10,4,5,6,7,8,15,2),c(2,5,5,14,16,8,15,17))
g =c(  rep("A",8),rep("B",8))

data = data.frame(group = g ,t = t)
data$label = ""
data$label[10]= "g"
data$color <- 'black' # added this to color the other points
data$color[10]= "red"

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

myfun<- function(x) {
  r <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95))
  names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  r
}

ggplot(data, aes(x=g, y=t,label = label)) + theme_bw()+
stat_summary(fun.data = myfun, geom="boxplot")  +
geom_dotplot(aes(fill = color), binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=.5) + 
scale_fill_identity()
```

I think a better property to change is **fill**, but you change it back to **color**

*Edited the ggplot call to incorporate a suggestion about how to make the code more elegant.*

Comment: I agree about the use of `fill` but the way this should be done IMHO is by means of `aes(fill = color)` ... `+ scale_fill_identity()`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a much more robust approach.